# Prove that there exist a real number $p$ and a function $g$ with $g(0)=g(1)$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\omega^{1}=f(x)dx$ be a 1-form on the interval $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=f(1)$. Prove that there exist a real number $p$ and a function $g$ with $g(0)=g(1)$ by means of which $\omega^{1}$ can be written as $$\omega^{1}=pdx+dg$$  Any hint pls!! Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, you don't need that $f(0)=f(1)$, but $f$ should be $C^0$. Then, your 1-form is obviously exact and we can write $\omega^1 = dh$ for
$$
h(x) = \int_0^x f(y) \, dy, \quad x \in [0,1].
$$
Now define $p:=h(1)\in \mathbb{R}$ and
$$
g(x) := \int_0^x (f(y)-p) \, dy = h(x) - px
$$
Hence we have $g(0) = h(0) - 0 = 0$ and $g(1) = h(1) - p = 0$ and furthermore
$$
dg = dh - pdx \Rightarrow \omega^1 = dh = pdx + dg.
$$